# Walk over variants that share the same member and get it?

Tags: c++

In the example below, is it possible to create a function `getX` that walks over the variant cases and get the `x` variable?

```
#include <variant>

class A {
    int x = 0;
};

class B {
    int x = 1;
};

class C {
    int x = 1;
};

std::variant<A, B, C> variant;
```

One obvious solution would be:

```
int getX(std::variant<A, B, C>& variant) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<A>(variant)) {
        
    } else //...
}
```

but then every time I add a new variant it'd be tedious to write code that treats the new case.

Is there a more automated, perhaps `constexpr` way of doing this? I think it's even possible to do for different variable names in each class. The one call that works should be the chosen one for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "visit".  You can do this:

```
#include <variant>

struct A {
    int x = 0;
};

struct B {
    int x = 1;
};

struct C {
    int x = 1;
};

std::variant<A, B, C> var = A{};

int main() {
    int n = std::visit([](auto & obj) {return obj.x;}, var);
}
```

Note, passing visit a generic lambda (taking an `auto` parameter) is actually a template, so whatever type is in the variant, that's the type of reference obj will be.  I had to change your classes to structs so that the data was accessible.

Comment: I didn't specify the problem correctly. Here's a more detailed one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713792/how-to-return-the-variable-x-that-is-define-don-all-members-of-an-stdvariant I actually can't use std::visit because the lambda expects the same type