# How to return a member that is defined in all alternatives of a std::variant, even if the members are different types?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get a variant's member called `x` even if it has a different type in each alternative?

```
#include <variant>

class A {
    int x = 0;
};

class B {
    int x = 1;
};

class C {
    bool x = false;
};

std::variant<A, B, C> variant = A{};

template<typename R> R getValue(std::variant<A, B, C>& variant ) {
    //return the value of x here
}
```

On [Walk over variants that share the same member and get it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712888/), I asked the same question, but it didn't specify that I wanted to get different types of values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67713497/10116440) talks about `std::visit()` but that does not accept a lambda that returns different types.

Comment: `variant` holds an `A` so that is all you can get out of it.  If `A` can be converted to what ever `R` is then yes you can get the `A` out of the `std::variant` and convert it to an `R`

Comment: You should fix return type of `getValue` during compilation. It physically cannot return different types depending on `variant`'s value. So you have to decide what exactly `R` is: fix it on call-site, make it a common type of `int` and `bool`, or maybe make it a `variant<int, bool>`.

Comment: @RichardCritten the OP is not trying to get `A` from the `variant`, he is trying to get the `A::x` member, `B::x` member, `C::x` member, depending on what the `variant` is holding, but `C::x` is a different type than `A::x` and `B::x`

Comment: The return type `R` is a *type variable*. That **does not** mean "I'll return something and I haven't decided what yet". It means "You give me any type `R` and I promise I'll return a value of type `R`", which is a much stronger promise than you have the means to fulfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the signature and template of your `getValue` function, you would actually need to manually decide the type of `R` when calling it. So in main, you would call it like:

```
std::cout << getValue<int>(variant); // prints 0;
```

And if that is what you intended, then you can simply cast the `.x` to type `R`:

```
template<typename R>
R getValue(std::variant<A, B, C>& v )
{
    return std::visit([](auto &obj){return R(obj.x);}, v);
}
```

However, I highly doubt that's what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you look for, I believe:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto getValue(std::variant<Ts...>& v )
{
    using R = std::common_type_t<decltype(Ts::x)...>;
    return std::visit([](auto &obj){return static_cast<R>(obj.x);}, v);
}
```

Above code doesn't require you to state the type you want back but rather *deduces* it by using `std::common_type` of the variable `x` in all the different possible values in your `variant`.

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1f54902ea1a9db3

Answer (score 2):

One more approach, again using visit.   :)  One thing to realize is that `visit` doesn't just take a single visitor, but can take a full *overload set* of visitor functions, allowing different functions to handle the different values.
Thus you can flip the problem around and instead of trying to *return* one of the different values from your variant, you can provide *handlers* for the values and *send* the value to the proper handler.

For example, using the overloaded function-call operator in a struct:

```
struct A { int x = 0; };
struct B { std::string x = "2"; };
struct C { bool x = true; };

int main() {

    struct Process {
        void operator()(A const& a) const {
            cout << "Got an A: " << a.x << '\n';
        }
        void operator()(B const& b) const {
            cout << "Got a  B: " << b.x << '\n';
        }
        void operator()(C const& c) const {
            cout << "Got a  C: " << c.x << '\n';
        }
    };

    var = A{};
    std::visit(Process{}, var);

    var = B{};
    std::visit(Process{}, var);

    var = C{};
    std::visit(Process{}, var);
}
```

A "modern" popular alternate syntax utilizing a bunch of c++17 features (including CTAD, variadic templates, deduction guides, inheriting from lambdas, and variadic using declarations in just a few lines) also looks nice, and is approximately equivalent to the above, though the first 2 lines defining the `overloaded` class could be considered library code even if they do not make full sense yet.

```
// probably library code
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

struct A { int x = 0; };
struct B { std::string x = "2"; };
struct C { bool x = true; };

int main() {

    // and then we have this nice, concise syntax:

    auto process = [](auto & variant) {
        std::visit(
            overloaded{
                [](A const& a) { cout << "Got an A: " << a.x << '\n'; },
                [](B const& b) { cout << "Got a  B: " << b.x << '\n'; },
                [](C const& c) { cout << "Got a  C: " << c.x << '\n'; }
            },
            var);
    };

    var = A{};
    process(var);

    var = B{};
    process(var);

    var = C{};
    process(var);
}
```

Here's both versions together in Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/8T91W4T9G